# Как задать большой градиентный фон для изображения

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста..
Как задать такой градиент для сзади изображения?[image: сам градиент с изображением]

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью box-shadow (поиграйтесь с параметрами и подберите подходящую Вам тень):

```css
.wrapper {
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px -20px darksalmon, 0 0 100px -20px darksalmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`box-shadow` у дополнительного блока со скругленными краями.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.container img {}

.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 90px red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <img src="https://icdn8.digitaltrends.com/image/digitaltrends/screenshot_20200507-124732_settings-640x640.jpg" width=144 height=320/>

</div>
```